# Generating word list base on possible numbers/characters via Crunch in Kali Linux

Tags: text-processing, kali-linux, password, compression

I'm new to `crunch`. I'm trying to generate a list containing 8 character long words.

## I've tried

`crunch 8 8 > pw.txt`

It freezes my computer because it doesn't have enough space for that.

[image]

Is there a way to create a word list based on a certain number/character that I might have use to take **less** time/space to create ?

---

**possible password**

```
a2016010
b2016010
c2016010
.
.
.
z2016010
```

---

Any hints / suggestions on this will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Compressing the `crunch` output with `pxz` can save a great deal of space, but the tradeoff is CPU cycles.  Here's some output from a run in progress:

```
crunch 8 8 |       { sleep 1s ; pv -c -N raw ; } | \
    pxz -D 12 -c | { sleep 2s ; pv -c -N cmp ; } > 8letters.txt.xz 
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 1879443581184 bytes
1792377 MB
1750 GB
1 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 208827064576 
      raw: 1.11GiB 0:07:41 [15.1MiB/s] [                           <=>   ]
      cmp: 7.14MiB 0:08:18 [   0 B/s] [    <=>                           ]
```

Note that `pv` code, which shows the data rate for the raw `crunch` output, right above the data rate after `pxz`:

- It's taking about 7 minutes per GB, which means the job might need ***nine days*** to complete.
- But the compression ratio is consistently *better* than 100 to 1, so the output file should be *less* than 17GB.